# Magento2: Need current URL in HTML-head: Scripts and Style Sheets for hreflang

Tags: magento2, seo, hreflang

My question is about using Magento2 HTML-head to generate hreflang links.

In Admin Content Configuration Store View HTML-Head Scripts & Styles I need the current URL for hreflang.

I have tried with following, but this does not work:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::geturlhreflang.phtml"}}" />
```

And in this file :

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/template/geturlhreflang.phtml:

```
<?php 
$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$parsed_url = parse_url($actual_link);
$scheme = isset($parsed_url['scheme']) ? $parsed_url['scheme'] . '://' : '';
$host   = isset($parsed_url['host']) ? $parsed_url['host'] : ''; 
$path   = isset($parsed_url['path']) ? $parsed_url['path'] : ''; 
echo "$scheme$host$path"; 
?>
```

How can I get the current URL into the header?

Answer (score 3):

Use Below code to get current URL

> /** @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface */
>       $urlInterface = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
>
> echo $urlInterface->getCurrentUrl();

i hope it will be help you

Comment: When I put your code in geturl.phtml and flush magento cache, I get the following result in the header: `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="{{block class=" magento\framework\view\element\template"="" template="geturl.phtml" }}">` Is there something wrong with my `{{ block class ="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::geturl.phtml"}}"` directive in Magento Admin ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem above, so I would like to share the answer.

Instead HTML-head section of Magento admin, I added into

```
app/design/frontend/mysite/mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

<body> 
    ...
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="head.additional" as="head.additional" template="Magento_Theme::getlang.phtml"/>
    ...
```

And PHTML-File is in and looks:

```
app/design/frontend/mysite/mytheme/Magento_Theme/templates/getlang.phtml

<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://en.mysite.com<?php echo parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);?>"/>
```